# How can I use Angular's $compile function to generate a KML file?

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, kml

In my Angular 1.2.18 app, I have an array of objects consisting of a location name and latitude/longitude coordinate pair. I would like to generate a KML file consisting of a list of Placemarks corresponding to this array.

It seems like a good opportunity to use Angular's $compile service to generate the KML, but for some reason, the ng-repeat directive intended to generate the Placemarks is interpreted as a #comment node in the Angular linkFn.

My KML export function is as follows:

```
$scope.export = function() {

  $http({method: 'GET', url: 'templates/kml_export.xml'}).
    success(function(data/*, status, headers, config*/) {
      var element = angular.element(data);
      var linkFn = $compile(element);
      var result = linkFn($scope);
      $log.debug(result);
    }).
    error(function(data, status/*, headers, config*/) {
      $log.error('error while retrieving KML export template: ' + status);
      $log.error(data);
    }
  );
};
```

My kml_export.xml template is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>My KML Document</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Folder>
      <name>Exported Locations</name>
      <description>Placemarks generated from saved locations</description>
      <Placemark ng-repeat="location in $storage.savedLocations">
        <name>{{location.title}}</name>
        <description>{{location.notes}}</description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>{{location.coordinate.longitude}},{{location.coordinate.latitude}},0</coordinates>
        </Point>
        <LookAt>
           <range>{{rangeOf(location.zoomLevel)}}</range>
           <longitude>{{location.coordinate.longitude}}</longitude>
           <latitude>{{location.coordinate.latitude}}</latitude>
           <altitude>0</altitude>
           <heading>0</heading>
           <tilt>0</tilt>
           <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

$scope.$storage.savedLocations is the array of location objects, each with the properties referenced in the KML template (e.g. .title, .notes, .coordinate etc.). The $scope.export() function is called in my controller. (Yes, I'm doing DOM manipulation in the controller, sort of, but I never want to render the result in the browser, so a directive doesn't seem a suitable approach.)

In Chrome, outputting result to the console always gives the following:

[image: Console output from Chrome]

I'd expected that the ng-repeat directive would have been expanded to complete the template with the data from $storage.savedLocations.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3Pie with Angularjs - The effects of CSS3Pie are applied only to first element when using ng-repeat directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012925/css3pie-with-angularjs-the-effects-of-css3pie-are-applied-only-to-first-elemen)

Comment: @PaulSweatte - not quite seeing why you think this might be a dup?